# Angular-Material Radio button data is not binding while i select radion button

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Here im upgrading my code from bootstrap to Angular Material
This is my Bootstrap code its working

```
 <input  type="radio" class="form-control input-sm" value="Act" (change)="onSelectionChange('Act')"  name="sectionType" #sectionType="ngModel"  id="rdb1" checked=true  ngModel required>Act
```

I changed as

```
<mat-radio-group >
    <mat-radio-button  [value]="Section" (change)="onSelectionChange('Section')"name="sectionType" #sectionType="ngModel"  ngModel>Section</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Why I'm not able to Bind Data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use data binding at `mat-radio-group` level, not at `mat-radio-button`:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="sectionType">
    <mat-radio-button  value="Section" (change)="onSelectionChange('Section')" name="sectionType">Section</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

You may refer to [this](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples) official guide.

Comment: im Getting Error as  Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Comment: what is the name of property you have for binding at your code side?

Comment: I did nt Bind any Name Im using Like   <pre>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>   Here im Testing Whether its binding or Not

Comment: You need to declare a variable at your code side to bind the value in radio button in HTML, otherwise, it won't reflect.

Comment: value property seems not exist